# Percentage is not working in css3 translate only in case of opera

Tags: css, translate

I was just trying in css3 if percentage(%) works in translateY or translateX. But Except opera all the browsers are doing correct animation. But opera doing no animation. Why?
Here is my code.

```
.ribbon {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;  
    top:0px;
    z-index:-90;

    -webkit-animation: moveY 10s ease 0s infinite normal;
    -moz-animation: moveY 10s ease 0s infinite normal;
    -ms-animation: moveY 10s ease 0s infinite normal;
    -o-animation: moveY 10s ease 0s infinite normal;
    animation: moveY 10s ease 0s infinite normal;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveY {
    0%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%); }
    50%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0px); }
    60%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(0px); }
    100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(100%); }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveY {
    0%{ -moz-transform:translateY(-100%); }
    50%{ -moz-transform:translateY(0px); }
    60%{ -moz-transform:translateY(0px); }
    100%{ -moz-transform:translateY(100%); }
}

@-ms-keyframes moveY {
    0%{ -ms-transform:translateY(-100%); }
    50%{ -ms-transform:translateY(0px); }
    60%{ -ms-transform:translateY(0px); }
    100%{ -ms-transform:translateY(100%); }
}

@-o-keyframes moveY {
    0%{ -o-transform:translateY(-100%); }
    50%{ -o-transform:translateY(0px); }
    60%{ -o-transform:translateY(0px); }
    100%{ -o-transform:translateY(100%); }
}

@-keyframes moveY {
    0%{ transform:translateY(-100%); }
    50%{ transform:translateY(0px); }
    60%{ transform:translateY(0px); }
    100%{ transform:translateY(100%); }
}
```